# Arkham: Harvey Walters Sanity loss for tome or elder sign

Tags: arkham-horror

Does Harvey Walters prevent the loss of one Sanity when he:

- uses an elder sign?
- succeed in reading a tome?

Which part of *The Dunwich Horror Rulebook* (page 10) apply?

> The Strong Mind ability only applies to involuntary losses. Voluntary expenditures to gain some benefit (such as casting a Spell) are not affected.

- To read a book gives some benefit (such as clue token or spell) so Sanity loss **is not prevented?**
- To use elder sign doesn't give a benefit to the character himself (he  seals a gate and removes a doom token) so Sanity loss **is prevented?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna throw some text at you (emphasis mine)

From the text on Necronomicon:

> Exhaust and spend 2 movement points to make a Lore (-2) check. If you pass, draw 1 Spell and **lose** 2 Sanity. If you fail, nothing happens.

From the text on Elder Sign:

> When sealing a gate, **lose** 1 Stamina and 1 Sanity and return this card
>   to the box. You do not need to make a skill check or spend any Clue
>   tokens to seal the gate. In addition, remove one doom token from the
>   Ancient One's doom track.

From Harvey's Strong Mind ability:

> Strong Mind - Any Phase: Harvey reduces all Sanity **losses** he suffers by 1, to a minimum of 0.

From the 'Casting Spells' section of the AH rulebook:

> Every spell has a casting modifier, and most have a Sanity ***cost***

And finally from the Fantasy Flight FAQ:

> Q: Does the Strong Mind ability (reduce all Sanity loss 
>   by 1) of the professor, Harvey Walters, apply to the casting of spells?
>
> A: No. The professor’s ability works on **losses**, not ***costs***. 
>   The same distinction applies to the gangster, Michael 
>   McGlen, and his ability to reduce Stamina losses.

I can see where'd you be confused due to the wording in the DH rulebook, but Harvey would reduce the sanity loss from both tomes and the Elder Sign. It's a fine line between paying some price in order to activate some ability and losing something due to activating some ability. If the text in question specifically states `loss` or `loses`, etc. then damage reduction abilities can be used.

EDIT:
For an additional example of cost vs. loss, consider the card 'Pentagram of Blood' from the Curse of the Dark Pharaoh expansion:

> Discard this card and X Stamina to ward your current street.

Or from the revised edition:

> Spend X Stamina and discard this card

**Loss** of staminia isn't explicitly called out in either of those ability descriptions. You could almost break it down as a 'Do X to do Y, then Z'. The necronomicon is '..spend 2 movement...to make a Lore (-2) check...then lose 2 sanity'. This wording structure won't work all the time, but hopefully it'll aid in determining when damage reduction abilities can apply.